# Reading data from a dynamic table in selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to read data from a dynamic table with selenium but I cannot locate the rows with Xpath. I want to read the first row data in the Price History table but selenium does not recognize the xpath. here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import os
import shutil
from selenium import webdriver
from pathlib import Path


link_temp = "https://www.trulia.com/p/az/phoenix/630-w-echo-ln-phoenix-az-85021--2288773138"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"./driver/chromedriver")
driver.get(link_temp)

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 2500)") 
time.sleep(2)

table_element = driver.find_element("xpath",  '//*[@id="main-content"]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div[1]')

print(str(table_element.text))
```

This is the error:

NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="main-content"]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div[1]"}
(Session info: chrome=112.0.5615.137)

Thank you for helping :)

I tired to read the first row of price history by xpath but selenium cannot locate it

Comment: Your code works without errors when I run it. Consider sticking a breakpoint in your code and (a) examining the page source of the page in the selenium-spawned browser and (b) experimenting with xpath expressions to see if you can narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It because this locator is not valid and since its an absolute xpath with so many indexes it breaks

```
//*[@id="main-content"]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/div[1]
```

Try with below code with , I have added a WebdriverWait to wait for Element dynamically instead of time.sleep which is bad practice and updated the locator to get the First Row Date column value for Price history table

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pathlib import Path
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link_temp = "https://www.trulia.com/p/az/phoenix/630-w-echo-ln-phoenix-az-85021--2288773138"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"./driver/chromedriver")
driver.get(link_temp)

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 2500)")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)  # wait up to 10 seconds
table_element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, '//div[@data-testid="price-history-container"]//table//tbody//tr[1]//td[1]')))
print(str(table_element.text))
```

Prints

```
09/15/2020
```